# Is there a way of excluding folders from i18n shell?

Tags: shell, internationalization, cakephp-2.0

Running the [i18n shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html) `extract` on my application costs a lot of time. On the commandline I can see that most of the time is needed for vendor libraries. Is there a way of excluding folders from the i18n shell?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the core app into it's own location and remove the vendor directory, then run the shell on the copy.